# First flutter app not starting on physical android device in android studio

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

I'm new to flutter development.
When I'm trying to run the default app on physical device, it is not even starting. It doesn't show any error but doesn't do anything too.
I even waited for more than 30 minutes but nothing happened, it consumed too much internet(don't know for what).
I have all the dependencies and requirements.
[see the result of running flutter doctor -v](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCBsO.png)

I have developed apps using Koltin and it runs without any difficulty.
Please help what can I do to get started.

Comment: Is your app installed on the physical Android device?

Comment: @YohanMalshika it just shows “Running Gradle task ‘assembleDebug’ and nothing happens after that, app doesn't get installed.

Comment: Can you try the "flutter run --verbose" command? And see if it's stuck on downloading some dependency or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This error got solved.**
If anyone else is facing this issue, then try doing these steps:

1.Go to **File -> Project Structure -> Project SDK** and select the Android SDK if it not selected. (Which was issue in my case)

2.Go to **Settings -> System Settings -> Android SDK** and uncheck "Android SDK Platform Tools" in the SDK tools section. And then install it again.

Now it will work fine